# preg_replace word inside html attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/" title="bar">Example</a>
```

How can I replace "bar" only in the href attribute?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to replace all links on the page containing bar? Only that exact link? Can you be a bit more specific about your goal?

Comment: I want to replace all the links on the page containing bar in the href attribute.

Comment: Just [don't do this with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: @Junuxx why not? not every utility function in the universe needs a complete HTML parser. While parsing HTML with regex is [certainly not ideal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), it's also not the end of the world to replace all hrefs with a certain string using regex; sometimes the right tool is the quick and dirty one and the question is very straightforward: how to do it with a regex; not whether a regex is the best tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start off by saying, [regular expressions are not the right tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). (At least not to find the attributes; for the replacement, probably...)

However, here is a regular expression solution anyway, but I cannot guarantee that it will work on all valid DOMs.

```
$newStr = preg_replace(
    '/(<a\s+[^>]*href="[^"]*)bar([^"]*"[^>]*>)/',
    '$1newString$2',
    $str);
```

Some explanation for the regex:

I start with a capturing group that ensures we are inside the `href` attribute of an `a`-Tag. The reason we capture this is, that it makes the replacement a bit cleaner. The `\s+[^>]*` allows for other attributes to come first, but not for the tag to close. The `[^"]` allows for more content in the `href` attribute to come first, but not for the attribute to close. Then we have `bar`. And then we add some more stuff before closing the attribute and then the tag.

The replacement then simply uses captured groups `$1` and `$2` (which contain everything around `bar`, which we had to use to make sure it's in the right place) but inserts the new string in between (where `bar` used to be).

Note, this will especially break if you have attributes containing `>` before the `href`-attribute!

Comment: Nicely done; are attributes containing `>` actually valid? Is it simply good practice or actual standard that they should be escaped?

Comment: I think they are allowed. However, this made me realise that my regex does not take single-quoted attribute values into account (omitting quotes altogether is not allowed if slashes are used, which is to be expected for `href` values).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, but the exact approach you would want to take really depends on whether you want to do this case-insensitive, for a specific link, or for all links in a page (i.e. globally) and the goal of your replace.

```
$var = preg_replace('@<a href=(["\'])(.*)/bar/["\']@', "<a href=\\1\\2/foo/\\1", '<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/" title="bar">Example</a>');
```

Comment: updated for your comments, and also because I munged the /g (that's for JavaScript; PHP defaults to global replace)